# Keynote slide with sound (interview) and synchronised scrolling text? Sound is about 4 minutes

Tags: audio, keynote, text, macos, slideshow

I have a transcription of an interview (text, one line per sentence and SRT), as well as the sound file itself. I want to present this content as both text and sound, with the text scrolling upwards on a slide in Keynote.

I think I want to advance to this slide and the hit space or something which should start both the scrolling and the sound.

How can this be done?

Keynote has a built in animation function but it is limited to one minute. I also haven't found a way to start the animation and sound by e.g. hit the space bar (but I am not an experienced Keynote user so it might be that I don't know how to achieve this).

I guess that if Keynote can't do this, I have to create a "movie", with scrolling text on a black background, and insert that. What are my options in that case?